# Double centralizer theorem: example and applications

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, representation-theory, noncommutative-algebra

> **Theorem:**  If $A$ is a finite-dimensional central simple algebra over a field $F$ and $B$ is a simple subalgebra of $A$, then $C_A(C_A(B))=B$.

In general (means, without condition on $B$, the relation $\supseteq$ holds in above.

Simplest (or trivial) example could be $B=A$ (am I right?). Then $C_A(A)=Z(A)$ and $C_A(Z(A))=A$.

(1) Can one give an elementary example of algebra $A$ and sub-algebra $B$ where strict inequality $\supset$ holds?

(2) Can one mention interesting applications of this theorem? (One may post a link also).

Answer (score 3):

1) $A=\mathbb C$, $B=\mathbb R$

2) you can see a few simple applications at the end of [this doc](https://www3.nd.edu/~ajorza/courses/m160b-w2012/handouts/algebra.pdf) regarding Davison rings and the Brauer group.